# I can't install APK with Android Studio "APK from app bundle" option for some situations. Is it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I am testing aab with android studio 4.1. I edit app configuration, and use "APK from app bundle" option, rather than "Default APK". For Android 11, I cannot install apk again if there is no code change. Is it a known issue? Is it an expected behaviour?

**For Android 10 and below:**

> Work as expected. If I run the app, MainActivity is launched, even if there is no code change.

**For Android 11:**

a) Install for the first time (new install):

> Work as expected. If I run the app, MainActivity is launched.

b) Install more than one time (with code update):

> Work as expected. If I run the app, MainActivity is launched.

c) Install more than one time (without changing any code):

> Apk from app bundle not installed, with the following message,

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\out\base-en.apk'
[1] 'D:\...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\out\base-master.apk'
[2] 'D:\...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\out\base-xxhdpi.apk'
The APKs are invalid.
Retry
```